# iOS Malloc error when accessing Dictionary value

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, memory-management

when I access a dictionary on the simulator everything is working fine, but as soon as I run the app on my iPhone 6+ the values in the dictionary can no longer be accessed.

When I try to print a value from the dictionary using the console `po dictionary["key"]` I get the following error, but when I run the same command on the simulator I get the correct value.

Also print the entire dictionary object using `po dictionary as NSDictionary` works with no issues in both simulator and device and I can see all the values in the dictionary.

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x100c88f60: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Does anyone know why this is happening on the device?

Comment: Post more of your code, please.

Comment: @picciano Thank you for responding, I cannot post the actual code here as this is a company project.

Comment: your question is far too broad to get a real answer without some code.

Comment: @LouisTur I understand, I knew this was a long shot since I cannot post the code.

Comment: Make sure you test in the simulator (and device) with zombies and memory scribble turned on. Likely the bug exists on the simulator but you are just not hitting it as memory is arranged differently.